# Remain the text in the center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the 'wishindia' in the center but when I add Login/SignUp it doesn't  remain in the center. Please help me doing this.

Code:

```
 .fontstyle {
     font-size: 2.5em;
     color: #ff3c00;
     font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
     text-decoration: none;
   }

.fontstyle:hover {
    color:#ef430e
}

@media (max-width:450px)
   {
        .fontstyle {
              font-size: 2em;
        }
   }

 .login  {
    float: right;
   }
```

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px;">
      <div class="custom text-center">
         <a class="fontstyle" href="#">wishindia</a>
         <a class="login" href="#">Login/SignUp</a>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the full code

Comment: try    .custom text-center a.fontstyle{ text-align: center;}   .custom text-center a.login{float:right} in your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
.fontstyle {
     position: absolute;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     //More code....
}
```

```css
.row {
    margin:0!important;
}

.fontstyle {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #ff3c00;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.fontstyle:hover {
    color:#ef430e
}

@media (max-width:450px)
   {
    .fontstyle {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

.login  {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px;">
      <div class="custom text-center">
         <a class="fontstyle" href="#">wishindia</a>
         <a class="login" href="#">Login/SignUp</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```